# Component props/functions not accessible within object

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have a React/Redux component that renders a calendar using fullcalendar.io. In creating the calendar object in componentDidMount(), it has certain properties I'm trying to manipulate. For example, the calendar object has a variables called "eventDrop" that is triggered when an even is dragged and dropped to a new location. I'm trying to use this function to make an API call to update the database using a method I passed in as a prop from my parent class. However, it's not allowing me to access any props in this function, stating an error message of "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'updateShift' of undefined or null reference." It doesn't allow me to even call any function in my component, stating "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'fetchData'."

```
export default class Index extends React.Component {
   //constructor()…

    componentDidMount() {

        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
        var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
            //Variables....

            eventDrop: function(info) {
                 // In this function, I cannot access state, props, or any other functions in the component
                 //CAUSING THE ERROR!
                this.props.updateShift(shift)
            }
        })
        calendar.render()
    }
}
```

And here's the parent class where I define the props.

```
export class VolunteerScheduling extends React.Component {
   //Constructor & other functions...


  render() {
    return (
                <Index
                  volunteers={this.props.volunteers}
                  getVolunteer={this.props.getVolunteer}
                  updateShift={this.props.updateShift}
                />
)}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({

  volunteers: selectors.volunteer.getAll(state),
  getVolunteer: selectors.volunteer.getOne(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateShift: (shift) => dispatch(updateShift(shift))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow function where you are trying to access the scope of this:

```
eventDrop:(info) => {
                 // Now you can access this.props or this.state here

                this.props.updateShift(shift)
            }
```

You can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@sgg2123/arrow-functions-in-js-ff54f558185b)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! My inexperience with ES6 is showing